# How to set 'Not Going' and 'Not Interested' event status via Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know how to set 'Going' and 'Interested' status for certain event via Facebook Graph API:

```
POST /{event_id}/attending
POST /{event_id}/maybe
```

But how to remove this status via API (like pressing buttons 'Not Going" and 'Not Interested' on Facebook site)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
POST /{event_id}/declined
```

I just tested it in the API Explorer and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It returns "Unsupported delete request. Object with ID '{event_id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."